# Count the number of rows that have values and put it in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have two data frames like this:

df1:

```
     col1    col2          time
0    A        A_1          05:02:03
1    A        A_2          15:36:14
2    A        A_1          28:21:47
3    A        A_2             NaN
4    B        B_1          52:28:01
5    B        B_2            NaN
6    B        B_1          52:28:01
7    B        B_1          52:28:01
```

I want to count how many rows have timestamp in column "time" in this dataframe and create a datafarme that looks like this:

```
   col1     col2    count
0   A        A_1     2
1   A        A_2     1
2   B        B_1     3
3   B        B_2     NaN
```

i tried this code:

```
df.col2.value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
```

but it is showing me only this:

```
    col2    count
0   A_1      2
1   A_2      1
2   B_1      3
3   B_2      1
```

The first problem is that i also want col1 in the dataframe, the second problem is that in B_2 i want the output to be NaN because it was no timestamp there.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` + `.count()`. Just replace zeros with `NaN`:

```py
x = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"], as_index=False).count().replace(0, np.nan)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2  time
0    A  A_1   2.0
1    A  A_2   1.0
2    B  B_1   3.0
3    B  B_2   NaN
```